# Is there a preferred way to list errors in response to a API request?

Tags: json, api

I'm building a JSON REST API. Some of the API actions require attributes. In case a API request to those actions is made without all the required attributes, the API returns a 4xx HTTP code and the list of missing attributes in JSON format.

For now, this JSON response only contains an object with the "errors" key storing an array of error messages. For example:

```
{"errors":["'first_name' attribute is missing","'title' attribute is missing"]}
```

So the API consumer just have to check if the "errors" key is null or contains an array of error messages.

Do you think that might be enough? This is a vague question, I'm looking for best/recommended practices to report such errors, to make the consuming of the API more natural and easy.